# How to pass data from view to parent layout?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Sorry that I need to paste so much code, but I assume this is necessary to understand my structure.

I have a users resource `Route::resource('/clients', ClientController::class)->middleware(['auth']);`

For the route `users.show` I have this function in my `UsersController`:

```php
public function show(Client $client)
{
    return view('clients.show', [
        'client' => $client,
    ]);
}
```

Then I have my `clients.show` view simplified with

```
<x-client-layout>

    Bla Bla ...

</x-client-layout>
```

and I my `layouts.client`

```php
@include('core.header')


    @include('layouts.navigation-client')

    <main class="flex flex-col w-full min-h-screen">

        {{ $slot }}
        
    </main>

@include('core.footer')
```

Now for the `layouts.navigation-client` I want to create a link to the route `Route('users.show', $client->id)`. But how can I pass the `$client` to the navigation view?

```
<x-nav-link :href="Route('users.show', $user->id)" :active="request()->routeIs('users.show')" icon="user">
```

What would work, but feels bad to do is:

```
Route('users.show', explode("clients/", url()->current())[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `users.show` view you can pass the client id to the `<x-client-layout>`.

```html
<!-- users.show view-->
<x-client-layout :client="$client">
    <!-- component markup -->
</x-client-layout>
```

Just make sure to define a default value for `$client` in the `<x-client-layout />` component, say a Client with `$client->id = 0`, otherwise you may get an undefined error.

You can also conditionally display the link only when `$client->id` has a value other than `0` - that way you can set the default value to `0` and use the `<x-client-layout />` for other views where you don't require the `$client->id` and there's no need to display the link.

Then you can pass the `$client` to the `layouts.navigation-client` and then use it for the `<x-nav-link />`

```php
@props([
   'client'
])
@include('core.header')


    @include('layouts.navigation-client', ['client' => $client])

    <main class="flex flex-col w-full min-h-screen">

        {{ $slot }}
        
    </main>

@include('core.footer')
```

And then in `layouts.navigation-client`

```php
<x-nav-link :href="route('users.show', $client->id)" :active="request()->routeIs('users.show')" icon="user" />
```

Comment: For this I get `Undefined variable $client` on the include line

Comment: Sorry, I misread the view hierarchy in the question. Have updated the answer

Comment: I would like it better if I pass the entire `$client` to the parent. Thus I'd have more freedom  to potentially display the name as well. But when I do `:client="$client"`
, I get again a `Undefined variable $client`

Comment: For any variable you want to use in the view of a blade component, it must be defined for the component. So to use `$client`, it must be defined as a prop for `<x-layout-client>` then you can pass it from `users.show` as `<x-layout-client :client="$client" />`

Comment: Have updated the answer to reflect passing entire `$client` object instead of just id

Comment: It is working with the props. Thank you very much